# 32 bit process consuming more memory in 64 bit os?

Tags: windows, memory-management, 32bit-64bit, ram

I have written one process. If Run that process in 32 bit windows OS it is consuming around 100 to 200MB of memory, And the same process if i run on 64 bit Windows OS it is consuming around 1GB of memory. Can anybody explain me Why this is happening.?

Thanks and Regardsm
shahid nx

Comment: Have you got the flag set to use more than 2GB of memory set on the 32bit version? What are you using to measure the memory usage, private bytes under perf counters?